Issue with @GeneratedValue and SequenceStyleGenerator on SQL Server 2019/2022 with Hibernate 6.4.4
We are using 4 database: Oracle, SQL Server 2019 & 2022, and MySQL
Hibernate:6.4.4
@Id
    @GenericGenerator(
        name = "sequenceGenerator",
        type = SequenceStyleGenerator.class ,
        parameters = {
            @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = "optimizer",value = "pooled-lo"),
            @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = "initial_value",value = "1"),
            @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter( name = "increment_size", value = "5" )
        }
    )
    @GeneratedValue(
        strategy = GenerationType.AUTO,
        generator = "sequenceGenerator"
    )
    private Long id;

When I insert record to DB it works with MySQL and Oracle. However it throws an exception on SQL Server

org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute statement [Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'X' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.] [insert into ledger (.//) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)]; SQL [....]) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)]

Yes, I don’t set any IDs manually.
The funny part it doesnt throw exception when inserted X record, it throwException when fetch it.(I verified the records in db).
When I change GenerationType as IDENTIFY
@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

It starts working properly. However, I prefer not to change the GenerationType because we are using four databases.
Besides all, this why this weird issue happening, any idea ?

The id column shouldn't be an identity, so the question is ,why does it become that? Is there some other config being done? Or was the column the identity before?

No it wasn't identity. I did change as a identity .Currently it is GenerationType.AUTO
